# Views Slideshow - How to add link on Pager that can link to original page?

Tags: navigation, paging, views

[Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) on Drupal 7 has a feature that can “Activate Slide and Pause on Pager Hover”. How can I add link on Pager, so when click, it actually link Pager to original piece of content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it actually can be very simple in Views setting.

1. add a "**Content:Path**" field. Set this "**Exclude from display**" and check "**Use absolute link**" on Rewrite results.
2. add another field that use for pager. I use "Content: pagericon" as my example .
3. Set this Pager field exclude from display and insert "**[path]**" as **Link path** Replacement patterns on "**Output this field as a link**".
4. back to the Format settings for Slideshow. Check the "**Pager**" under Top or bottom Widgets with "**Pager fields**", and check a field that use for pager. (I use "Content: pagericon" as my example)

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at the views slideshow code it seems that all the sections of the views slideshow are easily themed.

In the views slideshow module there is a themes folder with template files that can be overridden.

Though there is not a template file for the pager, instead there is a function in the file `views_slideshow.theme.inc`. The function you are interested in is probably `theme_views_slideshow_pager_widget_render($vars)` and this can be overwritten.

In your themes template.php copy and paste this function and rename it to `MYTHEME_views_slideshow_pager_widget_render($vars)`, (replacing MYTHEME with the name of your theme).

You should then be able to modify it in any way you like.

Comment: its good to know this but I'm looking for something that can be done within Views setting